# BroadCastReceiver. What's wrong in my code?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, alarm

Code of Receiver:

```
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

          try {
                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(
                        new FileReader(MainNote.log));


                String AlarmString;
                int i = 0;


                while ((AlarmString = in.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    Long AlarmTime = Long.parseLong(AlarmString.substring(0, AlarmString.indexOf(" ")));
                    if (AlarmTime < System.currentTimeMillis()) i++;
                    else {
                        String AlarmArray[] = AlarmString.split("\\s");
                        Intent AlarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
                        if (AlarmArray[1].equals("null")) AlarmIntent.putExtra("alarm_message", "");
                        else AlarmIntent.putExtra("alarm_message", AlarmArray[1]);
                        if (AlarmArray[2].equals("true"))
                        AlarmIntent.putExtra("Vibration", true);
                        else AlarmIntent.putExtra("Vibration", false);
                        if (AlarmArray[3].equals("true"))
                        AlarmIntent.putExtra("Sound", true);
                        else AlarmIntent.putExtra("Sound", false);

                         final int _ID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis(); 
                         PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context , _ID, AlarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                         AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                         am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, AlarmTime, sender);
                    }
                }
```

Code of AlarmReceiver.class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
     String message = bundle.getString("alarm_message");
     boolean Vibration = bundle.getBoolean("Vibration");
     boolean Sound = bundle.getBoolean("Sound");
     if (message.equals(null))
     NotifierHelper.sendNotification(context, MainNote.class, context.getResources().getString(R.string.NotTitle), context.getResources().getString(R.string.Nodiscr), 1, Sound, true, Vibration);
     else 
     NotifierHelper.sendNotification(context, MainNote.class, context.getResources().getString(R.string.NotTitle), message, 1, Sound, true, Vibration);
 }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />    

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MainNote">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".FingerPaint"></activity>
    <receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action                      
android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>     
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MainNote.log can costist for example

```
1304094118826 text true true
```

After reboot I see that my process is started, but then I dont have Notifacation. Whats wrong here? And how to debug code in OnBootReciever?

I replace my code in OnBootReciever on

```
Intent AlarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        AlarmIntent.putExtra("alarm_message", "blabla");
        AlarmIntent.putExtra("Vibration", true);
        AlarmIntent.putExtra("Sound", true);

         final int _ID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis(); 
         PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context , _ID, AlarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
         AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+6000, sender);
```

And its work. So problem in part where I read information from file.

One problem was in MainNote.log. Log its static varible so I cant contact with this here. But now I have very strange problem -

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/AlarmsFromDrawNote.alm (Permission denied)
com.notedraw.bos.app.OnBootReceiver1.onReceive(OnBootReceiver1.java:30)
```

30th line is -

```
BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(log));
```

WTF? (see manifest)

Answer (score 1):

Your AlarmReceiver needs to be a static BroadcastReceiver like your OnBootReceiver is in order for it to act on the alarm that you set. Unfortunately, I don't think you can have more than one static receiver per application (I tried before and it did not work for me). You could try putting two intent filters on your OnBootReceiver and have it deal with both broadcasts.

In your onRecieve, simply check `intent.getAction()` to see which broadcast it is receiving (the boot up one or the alarm), and deal with it appropriately.

Comment: But in [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemServices/Alarm/src/com/commonsware/android/syssvc/alarm/) example are two Receivers and it works. Now I've noticed that after reboot in logcat appears message near my process " Mistake in BootReciever Java.lang.NullPointerException : Argument must be not bull".

Comment: If that example does work, then you may want to try removing `android:process=":remote"` from your AlarmReciever in AndroidManifest.xml. His example does not use it. If it still does not work, please post the section of code that your NullPointerException is referring to.

Comment: I edited my frist message. Problem is in part where I read information from file. Thank you for help

Comment: Make sure that each index of your AlarmArray is not null before you call `.equals` on it. If that doesn't help, can you post the portion of your stacktrace with the NullPointerException?

Comment: I cant show a stacktrace because I see it not in debug mode. It just line in logcat. And I cant understand where are NullPointer without debug mode. Is there way to connect debuger after rebooting of device?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? You should just be able to plug your device in while Eclipse is running and watch the Logcat in realtime. You should also be able to run your app in debug mode as well if you click the button to the left of the green Run button.

Comment: Debuger disconnected from device after rebooting! And then it show just system messages, one of this is Mistake in BootReciever Java.lang.NullPointerException : Argument must be not null. Its not show line number which it causes.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. Put a try/catch around your `onReceive`, and in the catch call `exception.printStackTrace()`. You should get some more detail in your Logcat that way.

Comment: This code works well in other place, so I think problem can be in read file at short period after device boot.

Comment: One possible problem could be that when your BroadcastReceiver is called, your SD card isn't done mounting since the phone is still booting up. Try putting your file on the internal storage instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new broadcast receiver inside the class where the broadcast will be received.  Put this at the top of your class outside any methods.

```
AlarmReceiver intentReceiver = new AlarmReceiver ();
```

And you need:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Mark time user logged out
    unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}`
```

And:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(CustomAction.MY_INTENT);
    filter.addAction(CustomAction.MY_INTENT);
    registerReceiver(intentReceiver, filter);
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: I have 2 classes that extended BroadCastReciever class ( I edited my first message, because "public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver" wasnt here). So i dont understand how can I add onPause() and onResume() methods in those classes. I'll try to explame what i want: OnBootReceiver should start after boot and it should take some information from file (time message and other) and then in time it should fire AlarmReceiver. AlarmReceiver should start Notification.